# Is it possible to read the article from the this ResearchGate page as a nonresearcher? If so, how?

Tags: publications

I found the page https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301502255_Can_we_believe_it_Evidence_for_Christianity that I Google searched for. It's just the abstract. I couldn't figure out how to read the article under the abstract. I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop from 2011. I read the review that appears just before posting this question and I don't know enough to tell by reading the title of the questions and skimming the small bit of text under them that appears in the review.

Answer (score 6):

The author of this book has not uploaded any full text of the book to ResearchGate, so no one can read it there. You can ask the authors for a full text by clicking on "Request full text", but there is no guarantee that they will honor that request (especially for a book which is being sold on the market).

If a full text is available on ResearchGate, then the button "Request full text" is not present, and there is a "Download" button. See [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357363190_Electron-Optic_System_With_High_Compression_of_a_Multiple_Elliptic_Electron_Beam_for_a_Miniaturized_THz-Band_Vacuum_Electron_Device) for example.

Comment: I didn't pay attention carefully when I accepted this answer. When I clicked download citation, I accessed only the abstract which should men the full text is not available and so a link saying "Request full text" should be there but it's not. Maybe It's because I'm not a researcher. An answer that actually explains how it works in a way I can understand will probably suffice.

Comment: @Timothy strange. When I open your link in a private window (not logged in to ResearchGate (RG)), I get a popup with the button "Request full text". The [help center](https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/Discovering+and+requesting+research) of RG also says that the "request full text" button is available to everyone, even logged out users. Try to access your link on a private window and see if the popup comes. You can also create an account on RG as "not a researcher" and see if the button appears when using that account.